# Remove string prefix from first column

Tags: sed, prefix

I need to remove the prefix `chr` in the first column

```
column1  column2
chr1     123456
chr2     125679
```

to look like

```
1        123456
2        125679
```

I tried `sed -i 's/chr//g'`,  but it will create an empty space.

Comment: I've updated the title, it said "add" when you clearly want to remove a string.

Comment: What do you mean "it will create an empty space"? You mean you don't want the columns to get misaligned with the headers? Is leading whitespace on the first column values ok? Or do you need the space added to the "middle" of the line?

Comment: Sorry Benjamin W, yes i meant remove

Comment: yes I don't want the columns to get misaligned with the headers. leading space on the first column is ok, it will start with numbers 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: any sed command that can do the work please?

Answer (score 0):

try this one without the g

```
sed -i 's/chr//'
```